# comparing columns with in dataframe and count frequency of match in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 columns and would like to compare these two.

```
 Original  predicted
    x        x
    x        x
    x        a
    y        y
    y        y
    z        z
    z        z
    z        b
    z        z
```

and i want to get a different dataframe as output like

```
  Original total Correct wrong accuracy 
    x       3      2      1      0.67
    y       2      2      0      1.00
    z       4      3      1      0.75
```

I have tried groupby, but could not get the correct match count.

also if possible a confusion matrix

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMXIo.png)

Comment: tried this approach - https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html

Comment: The image is misleading with multiple columns. What are you comparing and what result are you expecting?

Comment: I have a text dataset with 3100 rows, and around 120 unique values in original...I want to compare both the columns and create an output dataframe with 120 unique values and their matching accuracy etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data = {'orig':['x','x','x','y','y','y','z','z','z','z'],
'pred':['x','x','a','y','b','y','z','c','c','z'] }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#compare results
df['correct'] = df.orig == df.pred
#group by on the desire columns
grouped = df.groupby('orig').agg({'orig': 'size','correct': 'sum'})
grouped['acc'] = grouped['correct'] / grouped['orig']
print(grouped)


      orig  correct       acc
orig                         
x        3      2.0  0.666667
y        3      2.0  0.666667
z        4      2.0  0.500000
```